# elsarticle twocolumn format, table environment interrupts references

Tags: elsarticle

I am using the `elsarticle` document class with the two column option as so:

```
\documentclass[preprint, 12pt, 3p, twocolumn, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
```

I haven't had any issues until now. I need to a insert a table towards the end of my text (before the references). I understand that a table can be inserted across two columns using `begin{table*}`. This does work but it seems to be only able to place the float at the top of a page. Because of this, it interrupts my references (see image). My other `begin{table*}` and `begin{figure*}` floats in the document are fine but this because they're at the end of the document.

[image: Image of a table interrupting references in LaTeX]

The only solution I can think of is the ditch the `twocolumn` option in the document class and then use `\begin{multicols}{2}` around my text and stop it before my table.

There must be a better way than this, surely so that I can continue to use the `twocolumn` option in the document class? Any advice would be great.

Comment: where do you want the table to appear? You can move it earlier in the source so that it appears a page earlier before your references.

Comment: I note you have two **references** headings?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hello. Yes, the two reference headings are there as a result of me modifying a working example of a [template using elsarticle ](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions). I will remove one when I'm finished editing.

I suppose just moving it somewhere would be the easiest option.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In fact, moving it has solved my issues. Sorry - I am very new to `LaTeX`. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double column float appears at the earliest the page after its appearance in the source, but you can arrange for it to come on an earlier page in the output simply by moving it earlier in the source.