Full width algorithm2e always floats to the next page
I am using a fill-width algorithm in two columns mode; however, it always floats to the next page even though the current page is empty:
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm*}
  a+b=c\;
  \caption{title}
\end{algorithm*}
This is a sample algorithm.
\end{document}

[ht] float specifier has no effect. [H] results in this error:
[H] in two columns mode is not allowed for algorithms.


Are you sure there is enough space before and after the algorithm?

@Emanuele Nardi, even if the page is completely empty with noting on it, it still floats to the next page. The code I provided will show that. \begin{algorithm} works fine but it's single column, \begin{algorithm*} always floats to the next page.

It seems to be related to the fact that the document class is in two-column mode, I think the float positioning algorithm places it after the current text.

Is using \ref to reference the algorithm unacceptable?

If there is nothing on the page, [htbp] places it correctly on the same page. However, if there is even a single line of text on the page, it still floats to the next page.

I tried \ref, didn't work, whether i place the algorithm before or after the single line of text, it still floats to next page.

Double column floats always go at the earliest at the top of the next page. That is unrelated to algorithms you would see the same with figure* also h does nothing for a double column float, only t and p are supporetd by default.

Just move the float earlier in the source file.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592305/1090
